# How to configure multiple viewers for a file type in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I edit a markdown file in a normal editor, I prefer a WYSIWYG editor or an Instant Rendering editor.
When I diff to commit a markdown file, I prefer a plain text editor.

Are there any relevant configuration options?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem as yours, I opened this ticket https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/113730 and finally find an answer, I had this setting in settings.json

```
"workbench.editorAssociations": [
{
    "viewType": "vscode.markdown.preview.editor",
    "filenamePattern": "*.md"
}
```

removing it, makes diff works without preview

Comment: In the diff editor, I perfer `"viewType": "default",`, because it can highlight the detail differences. While in the normal editor I prefer my extension viewer (such as `"viewType": "myEdit.markdown"`). Is there a way that makes both them working without changing settings repeatedly?